# remove background from radcombo box

Tags: css, telerik

I am using radcombobox to display data, now I am not using any css style for the radcombox, but it still has gray color background.

I want to remove that color. 
Below is my rad combobox code :

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadCountry" runat="server" CssClass="rcbInput rcbEmptyMessage"
                                           AutoPostBack="False" EmptyMessage="Select a Customer" EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True"
                                           ItemsPerRequest="10" ShowMoreResultsBox="True" EnableVirtualScrolling="True" Filter="Contains" DataTextField="Contact_First_Name"
                                           Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="11px" ShowToggleImage="false">
                                       </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I am also attaching the output of the given code.[image]

Answer (score 2):

i solve this by using below css

```
<style type="text/css">
        div.CustomCssClass .rcbInputCell INPUT.rcbInput {
            color: black;
            height: 1px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use browser debugger and goto to Inspect Element, find which class / element is the reason for background. Then overwrite css to background:none!important for that element / css rule.

Comment: it takes default css design of radcombobox from webresource.axd and i dont have any css or page by this name